# How to command Python not to count True as 1?

Tags: python-3.x

`count([5,2,1,'5',9,5,True],1)` will show 2 as it treat `True`as 1.How do i change my main code so that when I want to check how many 1 is in the sequence,it will only return 1.

this is my main code

```
def count(L,x):
    k = 0
    for i in L:
        if x == i :
            k+= 1

    return k
```

Comment: In python, True == 1 as shown with `print(True == 1)`, it prints True

Comment: yes it work!Thx!

Comment: Easiest solution for your exact case would be `if x == i and i is not True:`

Answer (score 1):

You can change `x == i` to `x is i`.

```
>>> x = True
>>> y = 1
>>> x == y
True
>>> x is y
False
```

Comment: This will work in most cases, but note that it relies on an implementation detail. It may not work on all Python interpreters, and it's not guaranteed to work in the future.

Comment: This will fail to compare numbers not being cached by python. For example `x = 999; y = 999; x is y // False`

Answer (score 1):

Just add an `isinstance` to your check:

```
def count(L,x):
    k = 0
    for i in L:
        if not isinstance(i, bool) and i == x:
            k+= 1
    return k
```

or, explicitly filter with `i is not True`. I.e `if i is not True and i == x:`